# Is it possible to abort ongoing connection using xinetd access_times?

Tags: ssh, xinetd

The `access_times` attribute in **xinetd** config file allows to limit access times for services.

What I want to know is if I have an opened connection (an ssh one) established in allowed time, how to force closing the connection when the allowed time has passed?

If not possible with **xinetd** itself given that I use **CentOS** 6 is there any alternative solution?